# $3$ Triangles and a quadrilateral

Tags: triangles, area, quadrilateral

In the following diagram, in $\Delta ABC$, $CD$ and $BE$ are two cevians intersecting it point $O$.
Area of $\Delta BOD = 3, \Delta BOC = \Delta COE = 7$. 
What is the area of $ADOE$.
**Note**: I can't find a way to solve this. Any hint will be helpful.

[image: 1]]

Comment: Perhaps this is the start of a solution: $BO=OE$ and $CO:DO = 3:7$. Then see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cevian.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: let $x,y$ be the area of $\triangle ADO, \triangle AEO$ respectively. Then: $O$ is the midpoint of $BE$ (why).So: $x+3 = y$.And $\dfrac{x}{y+7} = \dfrac{3}{7}$. Can you continue? Once you solve this system of equations , you know what $x,y$ are and the area of the quadrilateral is $x+y$.

Comment: How do you get $\frac{x}{y+7}=\frac{3}{7} $ ? Just curious

Comment: @stity Between two triangles, if their height is same then the ration of their area is the ration of their bases. So, $\dfrac{\Delta ADO}{\Delta ACO} = \dfrac{DO}{CO}$ So, $\dfrac{x}{y+7} = \dfrac{3}{7}$

Comment: @RezwanArefin thank you